# Get-AzADUser to filter by Domain in Mail field

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to do a PowerShell command line that can make a query to the Azure AD.
We have a few hundreds of users (between thousands) in our AD that have a Mail from a different domain.

I tried to use the

```
Get-AzADUser -Filter "endsWith(Mail,'somedomain.com')"
```

But the filter clause `endsWith` doesn't work with -Filter.

Also tried with `-SearchString` but does not work with the Mail column/value.

And I wanted to avoid to make a general query with a "where" pipe to filter, because it takes too long to process.

Answer (score 0):

It works but you need to use `-ConsistencyLevel Eventual` and `-Count` in your call:

- With Az Module:

```bash
Get-AzADUser -Filter "endsWith(Mail, 'somedomain.com')" -ConsistencyLevel Eventual -Count
```

- With Microsoft.Graph Module:

```bash
Select-MgProfile beta
Get-MgUser -Filter "endsWith(Mail, 'somedomain.com')" -ConsistencyLevel Eventual -CountVariable count -All
```

If you want to query the [users API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta) directly, you can use `Invoke-RestMethod` however this technique requires you to handle [pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging) manually:

```bash
$req = @{
    Uri     = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?`$filter=endsWith(mail, 'somedomain.com')&`$count=true"
    Headers = @{
        Authorization    = 'Bearer {0}' -f (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://graph.microsoft.com).Token
        ConsistencyLevel = 'Eventual'
    }
}
$response = Invoke-RestMethod @req
```